# Nested Json to Map using Jackson

Tags: java, json, dictionary

I'm trying to dynamically parse some JSON to a Map.  The following works well with simple JSON

```
        String easyString = "{\"name\":\"mkyong\", \"age\":\"29\"}";
    Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    map = mapper.readValue(easyString, 
            new TypeReference<HashMap<String,String>>(){});

    System.out.println(map);
```

But fails when I try to use some more complex JSON with nested information.  I'm trying to parse the sample data from json.org

```
{
  "glossary": {
    "title": "example glossary",
    "GlossDiv": {
      "title": "S",
      "GlossList": {
        "GlossEntry": {
          "ID": "SGML",
          "SortAs": "SGML",
          "GlossTerm": "Standard Generalized Markup Language",
          "Acronym": "SGML",
          "Abbrev": "ISO 8879:1986",
          "GlossDef": {
            "para": "A meta-markup language, used to create markup languages such as DocBook.",
            "GlossSeeAlso": [
              "GML",
              "XML"
            ]
          },
          "GlossSee": "markup"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I get the following error

Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_OBJECT token

Is there a way to parse complex JSON data into a map?

Comment: You want the result in a simple key/value map? How do you think the JSON data would be represented in such a map? What would be the keys and the values?

Comment: I think the error objects because the minute Jackson encounters the { character, it treats the remaining content as a new object, not a string. Have you tried defining your map as HashMap<String,Object>?

Comment: James no I haven't tried that yet.  Cyrille, what I'm trying to do is parse the JSON dynamiclly without having to create an object with a static structure.  The application I'm working on will be receiving JSON that I'll have no idea what the schema is ahead of time.  Ideally what I want to do is have some sort of mapping that holds the JSON so I can step through it from top down without knowing anything about it ahead of time and let the user select what data they want to have pulled back.

Comment: @user2229544 I tried HashMap<String, Object> , it works

Answer (score 21):

I think the error occurs because the minute Jackson encounters the { character, it treats the remaining content as a new object, not a string. Try Object as map value instead of String.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    map = mapper.readValue(x, new TypeReference<HashMap>(){});

    System.out.println(map);
}
```

output

```
{glossary={title=example glossary, GlossDiv={title=S, GlossList={GlossEntry={ID=SGML, SortAs=SGML, GlossTerm=Standard Generalized Markup Language, Acronym=SGML, Abbrev=ISO 8879:1986, GlossDef={para=A meta-markup language, used to create markup languages such as DocBook., GlossSeeAlso=[GML, XML]}, GlossSee=markup}}}}}
```

Comment: Great! Exactly what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 2):

Wrap your Map into a dumb object as container, like this:

```
public class Country {
  private final Map<String,Map<String,Set<String>>> citiesAndCounties=new HashMap<>;

  // Generate getters and setters and see the magic happen.
}
```

The rest is just working with your Object mapper, example Object mapper using Joda module:

```
public static final ObjectMapper JSON_MAPPER=new ObjectMapper().
          disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES).
          setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL).
          disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS).
          registerModule(new JodaModule());

// Calling your Object mapper
JSON_MAPPER.writeValueAsString(new Country());
```

Hope that helps ;-)