# How to persist a sub-document of arbitrary data to MongoDB using Spring Data?

Tags: java, json, mongodb, spring-data

I am trying to insert a document(json string) in a mongo db. One of the key "profile" of this has a value which is a json string. So, basically its a nested json structure. I know its possible to insert a nested json by abusing collection-refs / one-may relationships in the document class.

The issue I am facing here is that the json structure of the nested part is not fixed and hence cannot be abstracted to a java class as it is a custom data json fetched from social networking APIs. Defining "profile" as Java string inserts profile data with slashes thus escaping the double-quotes, curly brackets, etc. in json data .

Is there any other way without casting it to another object.

Answer (score 3):

The way to go is probably to make `profile` a `Map<String, Object>` in the containing class. This way, you can store arbitrary data within it.

```
 class MyDocument {

   Map<String, Object> profile;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer of using a Map was a little unclear to me... how do you convert an arbitrary JSON String to a Map in a way that Spring Data will persist it as-is?

I found that using a property of type "com.mongodb.DBObject" works.  Then set your property using JSON.parse:

```
profile = (DBObject) JSON.parse(arbitraryJSONString)
```

Comment: Spring data will persist Map objects containing nested Map objects just fine. Something like   
`Map<String, Object> dataMap = new HashMap<String, Object>() {{
            put("map", new HashMap<String, Object>() {{
                put("nestedProperty", "nestedString");
            }});
            put("nonNestedProperty", "nonNestedString");
        }};`
is easily persisted. To convert arbitrary JSON string to a Map, you can use Jackson Mapper. [This stackoverflow answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19841409/2125808) might help.

Comment: It sounds like that might work, but wouldn't it be preferable to do it in one line without extra dependencies as I did above?