# Remove DataSnapshot From Firebase setValue()

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My Firebase database storage format like this.

```
{
    key=3553: 3223,
    value={
        -KZMFwmCYKevESD6qtjD={
            text=Hello I am,
            timestamp=[
                .sv: timestamp
            ],
            imageUrl=,
            senderId=yDapbI755tOD72ivfsdferOv1RIHMnAe03
        }
    }
}
```

but at the time of set value to store in firebase database i am doing like this.

```
String Temp = "{timestamp: [.sv: timestamp], imageUrl: , senderId: " + Utils.SET_HEADER_ID + ", text: " + strMessage + "}";
System.out.println("===== Temp String : " + Temp);

String key = mFirebaseDatabaseReference.child("threads/3333:3333").push().getKey();
mFirebaseDatabaseReference.child("threads/3333:3333").child(key).setValue(Temp);
```

As I wrote above code I added a data in Firebase database. But it will automatically include DataSnapshot JsonObject at top my insert database format like this, which is wrong.

```
DataSnapshot{
    key=3333: 3333,
    value={
        -KZPfTKJhaCC4RkIj45P={
            timestamp: [
                .sv: timestamp
            ],
            imageUrl: ,
            senderId: yDapbI755tOD72ivOv1RIHMnAe03,
            text: hiiiiiiiii
        }
    }
}
```

How can I remove this DataSnapshot from insert format of Firebase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot pass a raw JSON value to Firebase. You'll instead have to build the data structure in your code:

```
Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
map.put("timestamp", Firebase.Database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);
map.put("imageUrl", "an actual image URL, which is missing from your question");
map.put("senderId", Utils.SET_HEADER_ID);
map.put("text", strMessage);

mFirebaseDatabaseReference.child("threads/3333:3333").child(key).setValue(map);
```

Alternatively you can use a library such as Jackson to convert the JSON intro the required nested map structure. See for example [Nested Json to Map using Jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19840818/nested-json-to-map-using-jackson).