# Working with Jackson to convert nested JSON to Map

Tags: java, json, jackson-databind

I'm currently using com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper to take a JSON string and convert to a map.  I'm struggling though to figure out how to work with my particular JSON input though and then how to Parse the output.  The JSON I'm playing around with looks like this:

```
{
   "data":[
      {
         "DATA.HELLO":[
            {
               "do_something":"true"
            }
         ],
         "DATA.GOODBYE":[
            {
               "do_something":"false"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Below is a snippet of my code.  Ultimately I want something like a Map<String, Map> where I can grab "do_something" or whatever other attribute from "data.hello" or "data.goodbye".

So I can do something like map.get("data") to get the array, but I'm not sure how to grab - for example - the DATA.HELLO piece.  I'm also not sure if what I'm doing here is the best way to handle this as this is the first time I've worked with Jackson and I'm fairly new to Java.  Am I on the completely wrong track here?

```
        String data = "{\"data\":[{\"DATA.HELLO\":[{\"do_something\":\"true\"}],\"DATA.GOODBYE\":[{\"do_something\":\"true\"}]}]}";
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Map<String, Map> map = mapper.readValue(data, Map.class);
        System.out.println(data);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Nested Json to Map using Jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19840818/nested-json-to-map-using-jackson)

Comment: So the solution in the link is quite close to what I've done so far I think.  The problem I think is that the structure I'm using doesn't properly describe my JSON?  So let's say I do Map<String, Object> map = mapper.readValue(data, new TypeReference<HashMap>(){});  .  Then for my data, the key is "data-collections" and the value is the rest of my JSON, which leaves me unable to further parse e.g. the array inside "DATA.HELLO".